# cant login to mysql cli due to this error unknown variable 'default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'

Tags: mysql

I already tried adding *default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password* in my.cnf but still error occurs.

Comment: The way I read it, it is telling you that it doesnt like what you have added.  Have you tried removing this line ?  Roll it back before you started fiddling with it.

Comment: @RohitGupta It was not originally in my.cnf before the error occurred. So i tried adding this default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password in my.cnf, but the its just the same issue. I cant log in now to MySQL due to that error.